# How to make a custom ListVIewItem on Secha2?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am trying to make a custom listview with his items bigger, with an image in the background and a text over it.

I'm trying to use the Kiva example on the docs, but I cannot understand nothing about how is doing that.

Someone could help me understand how to make that? or ar approach to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use sencha-touch 2.0, I think [Sencha-touch2.0 guide](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0) helps you.

Of course if you want to edit style, you must change via css or template of listview (via listview's tpl attribute).

Comment: Thanks, but I saw the Kiva explample, where they use other methond for do that.. i want to made a custom item on the "defaulType" of the listview... and the item tpl doesn't allow that...